# Items from asyncStorage do not appear when switching screens

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a problem, where data from AsyncStorage does not appear immediately when switching screens. But when a new application is refreshed, the data will appear.

Here's my function code:

*LoginWelcome/index.js*

```
_postData() {
    if(this.state.email !== '' || this.state.password !== ''){
      const dataAkun = {
        email: this.state.email,
        password: this.state.password
      }
      const paramsData = new URLSearchParams();
      paramsData.append('email', this.state.email);
      paramsData.append('password', this.state.password);
      axios.post('http://radarugi.com/rekber/login.php', paramsData)
        .then(function (response) {
          const resultArray = JSON.stringify(response);
          const kitaParse = JSON.parse(resultArray);
          if(kitaParse.data.statusCode == '1'){
            Alert.alert('Berhasil login!');
            this._updateData('akun', kitaParse.data.keyResult);
            this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeWelcome', {akun: this.state.akun});
            AsyncStorage.setItem('akun', kitaParse.data.keyResult);
            this.setState({
              akun: kitaParse.data.keyResult, 
            });
          }else{
            Alert.alert('Email/Password salah!');
          }
        }.bind(this))
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }else{
      Alert.alert('Mohon isi email dan password!');
    }
  }
```

*Home/index.js*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Image, TextInput, StatusBar, TouchableOpacity, Alert, KeyboardAvoidingView, AsyncStorage, BackHandler } from 'react-native';

export default class HelloWorldApp extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      akun: '',
    }
    this._showData();
  }

  _showData = async () => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('akun');
      this.setState({
        akun: value,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert(error);
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.backHandler.remove();
  }

  handleBackPress = () => {
    Alert.alert(
      'Keluar',
      'Apakah anda ingin keluar dari aplikasi?',
      [
        {text: 'Batal', onPress: () => console.log('Batal'), style: 'cancel'},
        {text: 'Ya', onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp()},
      ],
      { cancelable: false });
      return true;
  }

  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <Text>Selamat datang {this.state.akun}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the display when sending data with the _postData function:
[Switch to screen successful, but data does not appear.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxMub.png)

But when I refresh the application, the data will appear. The data should also appear when switching screens. Evidence of the data appears:
[evidence of data appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbXhT.png)

Comment: Lifecycle method componentDidMount is the right place to fetch data from somewhere and using setState() to set data of state. Avoid 1. setting state from constructor, 2. fetching data from apis.

Comment: try adding await in front of asyncstorage.setITem too

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncStorage.setItem` run async, so it may not finish update the item when you are trying to get it from `_showData`. You could try to navigate to `HomeWelcome` after successfully set the item. I converted your function to use async/await

```
async _postData() {
    if(this.state.email !== '' || this.state.password !== ''){
        const dataAkun = {
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password
        }
        const paramsData = new URLSearchParams();
        paramsData.append('email', this.state.email);
        paramsData.append('password', this.state.password);
        try {
            const response = await axios.post('http://radarugi.com/rekber/login.php', paramsData)
            const resultArray = JSON.stringify(response);
            const kitaParse = JSON.parse(resultArray);
            if(kitaParse.data.statusCode == '1') {
                Alert.alert('Berhasil login!');
                this._updateData('akun', kitaParse.data.keyResult);
                await AsyncStorage.setItem('akun', kitaParse.data.keyResult); <-- wait here
                this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeWelcome', {akun: this.state.akun});
                this.setState({
                    akun: kitaParse.data.keyResult, 
                });
            } else{
                Alert.alert('Email/Password salah!');
            }
        } catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }else{
      Alert.alert('Mohon isi email dan password!');
    }
  }
```